# Filter row based on matching substrings in cell values of another row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I have some data from which I'd like to return only cells that contain specific text.

In Row 1 I have a sequence of numbers, from 1 to 5, and in the row below each number a text string.

I want to FILTER Row 1 based on searching for text in the cells in Row 2.

1. The search values consist of individual letter characters.
2. Each cell I'm checking for the search values is  made up of multiple text strings separated by commas.  For example, `b,dec10` or `c,b,dec10`
3. A match is made if any one of the search values is found in the cell, but it must be a perfect match. For example,

   - `b,dec10` and `c,b,dec10` are both matches for `b` because `b` is a comma separated string in each of them.
   - `c,b,dec10` is a match for `c` for the same reason.
   - `b,dec10` is NOT a match for `c` because `c` does not exist as a complete comma delimited string.
   - `r,nov12` and `b,dec10` are matches for `r` and `b` because they each contain at least one of the lookup values.

#### Example Search

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| **2** | b,dec10 | x,nov12 | c,nov10 | c,b,dec10 | r,nov12 |

Using the sample data above,
a search for `b` or `x` should return `{1,2,4}`

I have tried the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(
   FILTER(A1:E1,
     (A2:E2="b")+(A2:E2="x"))
```

It returns values if cells in `A2:E2` contain `b` or `x` and nothing else, but doesn't return anything if there is anything else in the cell.

How should I modify my formula?

Comment: Is this in Google Sheets? Be sure to add the relevant tag.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity.  If I misinterpreted anything please [edit] and correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good candidate for combining FILTER and REGEXMATCH

## Formulae

#### 1.  Match `b`

```
=FILTER(A1:E1,
   REGEXMATCH(A2:E2, "(^|,)b(,|$)"))
```

Matches `b` if it is **both**:

1. **`(^|,)`** - At the start of the string **`^`** or **`|`** preceded by a comma **`,`**
2. **`(,|$)`** - followed by a comma **`,`** or **`|`** at the end of the string **`$`** 
   <sub>[image: Formula matches b]</sub>

#### 2.  Match `b` or `x`

```
=FILTER(A1:E1,
   REGEXMATCH(A2:E2, "(^|,)b|x(,|$)"))
```

- same rules as before except checks for either **`b`** or **`x`**
  <sub>[image: Formula matches b or x]</sub>

#### 3.  Match Cell Value

```
=FILTER(A1:E1,
   REGEXMATCH(A2:E2, "(^|,)"&G2&"(,|$)"))
```

- `G2` can contain a single value **`b`** or multiple values **`b|x`**
  <sub>[image: Formula uses a cell reference for the value(s)]</sub>

#### 4.  Match Values From a Range

```
=FILTER(A1:E1,
   REGEXMATCH(A2:E2, 
     "(^|,)"&JOIN("|",G2:G3)&"(,|$)"))
```

- Uses JOIN to concatenate a range of values with an or **`|`** operator as delimiter.
  <sub>[image: Formula concatenates a range of values with an or operator]</sub>

---

#### Function Support Links

[FILTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNpgn.png) [JOIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcOfR.png) [REGEXMATCH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3yHi.png)

Comment: Many thanks to @Blindspots for the suggestion, clarification and simplification. The formula you gave makes much more sense and easier to operate and modify than mine one, although I made my formula working after 3 days of experimenting :) as I use as criteria not "b" but "bb," or "cc,"..

Comment: @GeorgiSlaveev I presume you are aware that the answer above supports `bb` or `cc` or any other string you want to use.  I only used `b` in the example based on your question.